# How can we use pagination with angularjs without bootstrap style

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, pagination

I use Angularjs with pagination but i don't want Boostrap style for my pagination templte how can?

I try to edit these function in dirPagination.js in angularjs with my template pagination but it's seem to be not working anyone have some example for use pagination with angularjs but no need bootstrap style.

```
function dirPaginationControlsTemplateInstaller($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('angularUtils.directives.dirPagination.template', '<div class="col-md-12"><ul class="pagination"><li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{page-item disabled : pagination.current == 1 }"></li><li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{page-item disabled : pagination.current == 1 }"><a class="page-link" href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)"  aria-label="Previous"><span class="sr-only">&laquo; Prev</span><span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span></a></li><li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index" ng-class="{page-item active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == \'...\' }"><a class="page-link" href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)">{{ pageNumber }}</a></li><li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{page-item disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }"><a class="page-link" href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">Next &raquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li><li ng-if="boundaryLinks"  ng-class="{page-item disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }"></li></ul></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the paginator view file to not use the default bootstrap styling. See the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Pass a view file into the links method and any data you need to pass along with it:

```
{{ $paginator->links('view.name', ['foo' => 'bar']) }}
```

Comment: This is pagination with laravel but i use laravel with angular pagination